# $this->Authorization->authorize throwing error "Policy for Cake\ORM\Entity has not been defined" not working in CakePHP 4

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-4.x

As in the subject above.

I have been following the CakePHP 4 tutorial but instead of Articles I've used Properties. Everything is working great until I get to Authorization.

It seems the error is due to the property object being created as a generic Entity rather than in this case a Property object, although I might be wrong here.

```
$property = $this->Properties->newEmptyEntity();
```

skipAuthorization() works fine.

Here's a sample from Properties::add(). edit() and delete() behave the same way.

```
    public function add()
    {
        $property = $this->Properties->newEmptyEntity();
    
        $this->Authorization->authorize($property);
        ...
```

I have also declared a PropertyPolicy:

```
use App\Model\Entity\Property;
use Authorization\IdentityInterface;

/**
 * Property policy
 */
class PropertyPolicy
{
    /**
     * Check if $user can add Property
     *
     * @param \Authorization\IdentityInterface $user The user.
     * @param \App\Model\Entity\Property $property
     * @return bool
     */
    public function canAdd(IdentityInterface $user, Property $property)
    {
    return true; //Chicken and egg; you can't check a property ownership if it's not created yet
    }
    ...
```

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: In your `add` function, what does `get_class($property)` give you? How about `get_class($this->Properties)`?

Comment: Hi Greg, get_class(property) : Cake\ORM\Entity
get_class(this->Properties) : App\Model\Table\PropertiesTable

Comment: It's weird that the `PropertiesTable` would give you a generic entity. Are you calling `setEntityClass` in there? You shouldn't be. Is the file or class name of your Property entity class wrong? See [here](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/orm/table-objects.html#customizing-the-entity-class-a-table-uses) for some details.

Comment: In Application.php, have you add the  AuthorizationMiddleware  in the middleware ? Something like : `->add(new AuthorizationMiddleware($this))`

Comment: I've worked out the problem. The entity file name was Article.php instead of Property.php.  Thanks Greg for the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure at the top of PropertyPolicy, you defined the namespace:

```
namespace App\Policy;

use App\Model\Entity\Property;
use Authorization\IdentityInterface;
```

Exluding the namespace would cause the same error you described.

Comment: Good suggestion, but not the problem in my case unfortunately.

`
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Policy;

use App\Model\Entity\Property;
use Authorization\IdentityInterface;

/**
 * Property policy
`